# How to send and get mail using Mandrill?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, mandrill

I'm using Ruby on Rails, could you teach me how to use Mandrill to send and receive mail.

My problem is when user input text and press submit, I want message to be sent to my mail.
I have read documentation, but I don't understand it.

This is my development.rb, same as production.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :port =>           '587',
    :address =>        'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
    :user_name =>      'myemail@gmail.com',
    :password =>       's82SlRM5dPiKL8vjrJfj4w',
    :domain =>         'heroku.com',
    :authentication => :plain
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  def welcome
    mail(to: "morumotto26@gmail.com", subject: "Welcome", body: "Have a nice day")
  end 
end
```

and in controller:

```
def index
  UserMailer.welcome.deliver
end
```

My logs file look like this:

```
Started GET "/users/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-21 16:14:10 +0700
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML

Sent mail to morumotto26@gmail.com (2008.0ms)
Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2014 16:14:10 +0700

From: myemail@gmail.com

To: morumotto26@gmail.com

Message-ID: <52de3a62c89b2_5e8c9ea1881631@tnkjapan10.mail>

Subject: Welcome

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain;

 charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit



Have a nice day
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2018ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you will need to create account on the mandrill.com.

After log in, select type of integration: SMTP or API. SMTP will suite you in most of the cases.

Click SMTP, and create you API key.

Then in your development.rb or production.rb file
add these lines:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :port =>           '587',
  :address =>        'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  :user_name =>      ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
  :password =>       ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY'],
  :domain =>         'domain.com',
  :authentication => :plain
}
```

That's basically all. Now you can send email with Mandrill.

**EDIT**

Also try to add to your to your environment files these line to perform deliveries and raise delivery errors if any. Also add your default_url_options - in development localhost:3000, in production heroku.com

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }
```

Restart your app before testing

**EDIT 2**

If you want ActionMailer to send email on submit button click, then you will need to move `UserMailer.welcome.deliver` to create action of the respective controller.

```
def create
   if @object.save
     UserMailer.welcome.deliver
   else
     render "new"
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but I still not receive any mail yet.
`default from: "myemail@gmail.com"
  def welcome_email
    mail(to: blahblah@gmail.com, subject: "Welcome to my website")
  end`

Comment: Did you used your proper username and apikey? Temporarly delete `ENV[]` and just insert plain strings. Also ensure you have `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp` in your environment .rb file.

Comment: what's your log file looks like when you open index action?

Comment: I posted that file, I have tried to send mail for 2 days but I still can't do that :(

Comment: Rename `ActionMailer::Base` to `config.action_mailer` as in my answer.Also, you can try to move `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` = {} and `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method ` to your `user_mailer.rb` directly

Comment: Thank you, but It not working bro. I don't know why :(

Comment: See updated answer, will you have any errors if you add these lines? also check default_url_options

Comment: I am glad you were able to resolve it. Do you mind to accept answer then?

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to do that... I am glad to accept your answer